# Change upstream pushed commit

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I have two commits and both push upstream in master commit new and commit old.
Both of them should become PRs. Commit old should do base enhancements and commit two adds a feature. Now I need to add a fix to commit old.

what I did:

```
$ git rebase -i <commit_before_old>
```

applied the fixes

```
$ git commit --all --amend --no-edit
$ git rebase --continue
$ git push -u orign master -f
```

But this doesn't change the commit_old

Comment: `applied the fixes` *What* fixes? What did you type in the interactive rebase window, which commits did you pick, squash, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git reset --hard commit_old
```

apply fixes

```
git commit --all --amend --no-edit
git cherry-pick commit_new
```

resolve conflicts if needed and commit

```
git push -u orign master -f
```